# How to create a .devcontainer for a git repository that holds two different node apps with two different package.json files?

Tags: node.js, git, docker, mern, vscode-devcontainer

My repository is structured like so:

```
~/
-.devcontainer/
-- devcontainer.json
-- Dockerfile
- backend/
-- package.json
-- ... other backend files
- frontend/
-- package.json
-- ... other backend files
```

So the package.json for the backend is located at `~/backend/package.json`.

I'm trying to write a .devcontainer directory (to streamline development in vscode) in the root directory of the repo that consists of a `devcontainer.json` and a `Dockerfile` to build with. I want to simply copy the whole repo into the container and install dependencies.

I've tried doing this but I get errors relating to the ability for the Docker daemon to find `node:latest` in the `Dokerfile`. Here's my current `devcontainer.json` file:

```
{
    "name": "Project Dev Container",
    "dockerFile": "Dockerfile",
    "customizations": {
        "vscode": {
            "settings": {
                "terminal.integrated.shell.linux": "/bin/bash"
            },
            "extensions": [
                "dbaeumer.vscode-eslint"
            ]
        }
    },

    "forwardPorts": [3000, 3001],
    "postCreateCommand": "cd backend && npm install && cd ../frontend && npm install",
    "remoteUser": "node"
}
```

Here's my current `Dockerfile`:

```
# Use an official Node runtime as a parent image
FROM node:latest

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the rest of the project
COPY . .

# Expose ports for frontend and backend
EXPOSE 3000 3001

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

I would ideally to have a fresh developer of the repo be able to clone it, and open the repo as a devcontainer with a shell in the repo and the dependencies installed from both the backend and frontend. Any advice or solution is much appreaciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use devcountainer for two different apps with two different dependencies you should consider using docker compose along with vscode development features.

Docker Compose was developed to help define and share multi-container applications. With Compose, we can create a YAML file to define the services

Here is a link to guidelines for this
https://toptechtips.github.io/2023-05-17-docker-compose-multiple-dev-containers/

Also doc of vscode-devcountainer:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/devcontainers/tutorial#_how-it-works